# Calling REST Web Services in Android and getting null in String data

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am trying to call REST Web Service with the sampleURL by passing lat and lon and userID. But I always get `null` in String data. Any suggestions why is it happening? I am working with Android. But when I try to open that url in the browser, it gets opened and I can see the response. I guess something wrong in my code is there.

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            String data = findUsersInCurrentRadius(1,location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            System.out.println("Got Data" +data);
            textView.setText(data);

}

private String findUsersInCurrentRadius(int userid, double lat, double lon) {

        String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/"+REMOTE_METHOD_NAME+"/"+userid+"/"+lat+"/"+lon;
        System.out.println(sampleURL);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(sampleURL);
        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            System.out.println("Some Response" +response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            return e1.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the status code of your `HttpResponse`?  What if you made one tiny mistake in your request setup?

Comment: On which `android OS` you are testing? Btw `response` is null or `text` is null?

Comment: `String data is null` in my above code. Just to make clear to everyone, this is the full code above for calling and getting data from REST Web Services.

Comment: You are running your Network request on main UI thread. use `AsyncTask` to execute network request. Android OS > 3.0 does not allow to run `Network request` on main UI thread.

Comment: How can I do that. Can you show me an example basis on my code. By that way I can understand this thing.

Comment: Use this to bypass the strictMode on onCreate() method     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);    I dont recommend it though, just for testing and use AsyncTask to load your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your Network request on main UI thread. use AsyncTask to execute network request. Android OS >= 3.0 does not allow to run Network request on main UI thread.

you can use `AsyncTask` like

```
    private class NetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    int userid;
    double lat, lon;
    String reponse;

    public NetworkRequest(int userID, double lat, double lon) {
        this.userid = userID;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.lat = lot;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        reponse = findUsersInCurrentRadius(userid, lat, lon);
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (null != reponse) {
            System.out.println("Got Data" + reponse);
            textView.setText(reponse);
        }
        else{
            //Handle the Error
        }
    }

}
```

and then in your `onLocationChanged` call `Async Task`

```
new NetworkRequest(userid,lat,lon).execute();
```